# How to renew my own token expiration time after positive validation in Net Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, jwt

I have this configuration to generate the token:

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_tokenSetting.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
            {
                new Claim("User", JObject.FromObject(user).ToString())
            }),
            Issuer = "MyIssuer",

            /* Property to be renewed */
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),  
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        string realToken  = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return realToken;
```

And this for validation on ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
            {
                auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(bearer =>
            {
                bearer.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                bearer.SaveToken = true;
                bearer.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "MyIssuer",
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

How can I renew the "Expires" properties on each Token after positive validation?

Comment: I think most API/webserver send a new token (or modified) in the head of the message. The client will have to overwrite the old one with the new one given. So with every request add the new token to your head of the response. I know JAVA has a "provider" that makes it able to add it automatically before sending the response that way you don't have to add it to every function.

Comment: It might be that you're confusing something. When we hash some data (and jwt uses SHA algorithm) it means that we sign it with private key in order to *seal* it. If we need to modify this data for some reason - we can return *new* hashed data. You could check if a token is about to expire and return new token in response headers that client will consume

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Fabjan. I have the key for unhash the content of the token. I just need to renew automatically the property everytime the configuration services validate the token positively.

Comment: @Elvermg It's not really possible to 'unhash' the token... What is possible however is to read its *public* (unhashed) content that is located in payload part of the token... Copy your token to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and you'll see three parts - header, payload and hashed data that contains signature, if you need to modify the token - then you'd need to add a new hash into it, otherwise it will contain incorrect signature. So a way to do this is to create a *new* token

Comment: @Fabjan thanks, I know that. How can I get the new token generation automatically after the validation of the old token?

Comment: Check this article: [Refresh Tokens in ASP.NET Core Web Api](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/)

Comment: I was triying to avoid the use of another ActionFilter, but it looks like is the only way. Thanks @Fabjan.

Comment: I am not really sure what the 'best' solution is but I have created my onw Auth middleware that was doing this and some other stuff related to authentication.